# Firefox 50 Applocker issue

Tags: firefox, applocker

Since the latest update of Firefox, all our Terminal Servers (2008 R2 and 2012 R2) with Applocker enabled are unable to use Firefox, either for admins or users. It works only if you specify everyone or a specific user in the Applocker rule, but not for groups as it was before. With version 49.0.2 it works perfectly.

I think something in Firefox was changed that impact the way applocker rules are processed.

Could you please help ?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't find a report about this in Mozilla's bug tracker. If this is indeed a problem introduced in the new version, the most useful thing you could do to figure this out is to find the build in which the regression occured: http://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/